# how to shorthand a dictionary based search

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-operator, shorthand

In a pandas Dataframe, I'm checking whether the a variable is in the value of a dictionary, and if so return the key. else return the value.

```
def getModelType(row):
    for key, value in models.items():
        if row.MODEL in value:
            return key
    return row.MODEL
```

I'm tryin to clean up the code and write the expression in shorthand:

```
return key for (key,value) in models.items() if row.MODEL in value else row.MODEL
```

I keep getting a syntax error.
can this be shortened?

Comment: You need a `next` to get the first value from the iterator.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do (in the bigger context)? Please provide a full [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can *fix* your "shorthand", but it won't "clean up the code". Rather the opposite.

Comment: @PierreD I'm trying to check whether a value in the dataframe is a type of product. the product in the table is described by the model.
I've created a dictionary containing all the product types and their models, for example: {'Dog': ['Labrador', 'German Sheppard', 'Poodle'], 'Cat':['Scottish fold', 'Persian']}
if the value in the row.MODEL is 'Labrador', I'd like it to return 'Dog'.

My question is purely regarding the shorthand writing of my function.

Comment: Your "shorthand" is hard to fix, and in any case won't clean the code nor speed it up. One possibility I was thinking about was `return next(key for key, value in models.items() if row.MODEL in value) or row.MODEL`, but `next()` of an empty iterator (which is what you get if there are no matches) raises `StopIteration`. Another possibility is `return ([key for key, value in models.items() if row.MODEL in value] + [row.MODEL])[0]`. It is a one-liner, but it's as ugly as it gets, and hardly a "shorthand". And it doesn't fix the problem that the overall solution is way slower than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make a "reverse lookup" `dict`.

**Edit**: with additional comments from the OP, it looks like the `models` `dict` has a `{key: list, ...}` structure.

```py
rmodels = {v: k for k, a in models.items() for v in a}
```

Then, your operation with the Pandas DataFrame can become e.g.:

```py
df['MODEL'].apply(lambda v: rmodels.get(v, v))
```

This will substantially speed up the conversion.

Note: if there are duplicate values in `models`, your original code will select the first key (by insertion order) where the value matches. By contrast, the code above will keep the last.

**Addendum: speed**

Here is a quick setup to investigate the speed-up of this proposed solution.

```py
# 1. setup

n = 10_000
m = 50
c = 20
oovprop = 0.2
models = {model: [f'{model}_{j}' for j in range(c)] for model in [f'model_{i}' for i in range(m)]}
oov = [f'foo_{j}' for j in range(int(m * c * oovprop))]  # oov: "out-of-vocabulary"
alltypes = [v for a in models.values() for v in a] + oov
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'MODEL': np.random.choice(alltypes, size=n),
    'x': np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
})
```

Then:

```py
# 2. measurements

a = %timeit -o df.apply(getModelType, axis=1)
# 1.53 s ± 3.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

b = %timeit -o rmodels = {v: k for k, a in models.items() for v in a}; df['MODEL'].apply(lambda v: rmodels.get(v, v))
# 1.98 ms ± 2.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> a.average / b.average
771.67966
```

With 50 models, 20 types each, 10K rows including 20% of "out-of-vocabulary" types (i.e., not in any model), the speedup over applying `getModelType` is over 750x.

Comment: good catch -- hard to tell if that was an error or intentional without seeing some actual example.

Comment: ok, fixed after reading the OP's clarification.

Comment: lol, before first cup of coffee... Fixed. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next` with a default:

```
return next((k for k, v in models.items() if row.MODEL in v), row.MODEL)
```

Answer (score -1):

The else statement must be put at the beginning. Also, you don't want to return the generator, but only the first element of the generator, so you need to call the function `next` on it.

This should work:

```
return next(key if row.MODEL in value else row.MODEL for key, value in models.items())
```

Comment: This is way too eager to return the default.